# jquery get values from a form field and do math with them function not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, function, math

I have a function in jquery that on keyup it is supposed to do math with values from 2 fields, and change the values of my totalweight field with ID of totalweight, like so:

jQuery:

```
    $('#numberOfItems').keyup(function(){

        var items = $('#numberOfItems').val();
        var weightitem = $('#weightitem').val();

        var totalweight = items * weightitem;

        $('#totalweight').val(totalweight);

    });
```

---

HTML:

```
<div>
<form>
   <input type="text" id=weightitem"" placeholder="Weight per item">
   <input type="text" id=numberOfItems"" placeholder="Items">
   <input type="text" id=totalweight"" placeholder="Weight in total">
</form>
</div>
```

But this is not working... Could anyone help me with this matter?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: instead of `$('#numberOfItems').keyup` try `$(document).on('keyup','#numberOfItems',function(){})` and use `paresInt()` as shown by **Satpal**

Comment: please add your html as well, so i can make a jsfiddle with the exact problem and test it.

Comment: plus, please tell us what errors and problems you got with your code.

Comment: it doesnt display any errors... it just doesnt work at all! I alert something just to make sure the event "keyup" is triggered and it does but my code above just doesnt change the value of the div with the value from totalweight

Answer (score 0):

I have face the same issue before but I do not understand that why this occur.But I have solve it by declaring variable using $ sign instead of var.

```
 $('#numberOfItems').keyup(function(){

     $items = $('#numberOfItems').val();
     $weightitem = $('#weightitem').val();

     $totalweight = $items * $weightitem;

    $('#totalweight').val($totalweight);

});
```

Comment: only changing the variable name doesn't do nothing at all. if you used `$.variable` you would have made it a jquery global var. but with just adding the `$` you literally just changed the variable name. there must have been other issues with your code, that you have accidently changed (maybe just typos in variable names).

Comment: plus, in the short form of this code, you don't need a single variable name at all: `$("#totalweight").val( $('#numberOfItems').val() * $('#weightitem').val() );`

Answer (score 0):

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">    
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Hide</title>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>  
  <style type="text/css">
  label input[type="file"] 
{
display: block;
margin-top: -20px;
opacity: 0;
}
  </style>
  <script>
  var items=0;
  var weightitem=0;
  var totalweight=0;
  $('#numberOfItems').keyup(function(){

        var items = $('#numberOfItems').val();
        var weightitem = $('#weightitem').val();

        var totalweight = items * weightitem;

        $('#totalweight').val(totalweight);

    });
   $(window).ready(function() {
$(document).delegate('#numberOfItems','keyup',function(){

  items = $(this).val();
  weightitem = $('#weightitem').val();
  totalweight = items * weightitem;
  $('#totalweight').val(totalweight);
});
$(document).delegate('#weightitem','keyup',function(){

  items = $('#numberOfItems').val();
  weightitem = $(this).val();
  totalweight = items * weightitem;
  $('#totalweight').val(totalweight);
});

});
  </script>
</head>
<body>
<input type='text' id='numberOfItems'>
<input type='text' id='weightitem'>
<input type='text' id='totalweight'>
</body>
</html>
```